# MPAndroid : How to place the text inside the circle (without y-offset)

Tags: java, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I am developing a small chart app to monitor the blood sugar with the MPAndroidChart library.
Is there a way to draw the text inside the circle without offset?
As suggested in another post, i put in a slight y-offset (different y-data for circle and text) and achieved a result which is ok.
But if there are only two values the text and circle do not align.
I am not that familiar with modifying the yAxis Renderer, do you know how to find the formula behind the offset for the labels? (would be great to just recalculate it..)

Similar problem: [How to place the text values inside in MPAndroidChart circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788265/how-to-place-the-text-values-inside-in-mpandroidchart-circle)

[With manual offset between text and circle y-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF2we.png)

[Due to zooming in on y-axis (less data points and range on y-axis) the manuel offset is not working well here..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5glg.png)

Otherwise awesome library PhilJay !!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I have found a easy and sufficient solution:**

Override the drawValues method from LineChartRenderer**

In LineChartRenderer.java -> drawValues the text is vertically shifted by this line:

```
drawValue(c, formatter.getPointLabel(entry), x, y - valOffset, dataSet.getValueTextColor(j / 2));
```

So to get rid of the "- valOffset":

1.Override the drawValues method

Create a new java file "CenteredTextLineChartRenderer.java" and override method drawValues from LineChartRenderer

2.Modify the y-valOffset to y+textHeight*0.35f

Add float textHeight = dataSet.getValueTextSize();

```
public class CenteredTextLineChartRenderer extends LineChartRenderer {

public CenteredTextLineChartRenderer(LineDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
    super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
}

//Modified drawValues Method
// Center label on coordinate instead of applying a valOffset

@Override
public void drawValues(Canvas c) {

    if (isDrawingValuesAllowed(mChart)) {

        List<ILineDataSet> dataSets = mChart.getLineData().getDataSets();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataSets.size(); i++) {

            ILineDataSet dataSet = dataSets.get(i);

            float textHeight = dataSet.getValueTextSize();

            if (!shouldDrawValues(dataSet) || dataSet.getEntryCount() < 1)
                continue;

            // apply the text-styling defined by the DataSet
            applyValueTextStyle(dataSet);

            Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

            // make sure the values do not interfear with the circles
            int valOffset = (int) (dataSet.getCircleRadius() * 1.75f);

            if (!dataSet.isDrawCirclesEnabled())
                valOffset = valOffset / 2;

            mXBounds.set(mChart, dataSet);

            float[] positions = trans.generateTransformedValuesLine(dataSet, mAnimator.getPhaseX(), mAnimator
                    .getPhaseY(), mXBounds.min, mXBounds.max);
            ValueFormatter formatter = dataSet.getValueFormatter();

            MPPointF iconsOffset = MPPointF.getInstance(dataSet.getIconsOffset());
            iconsOffset.x = Utils.convertDpToPixel(iconsOffset.x);
            iconsOffset.y = Utils.convertDpToPixel(iconsOffset.y);

            for (int j = 0; j < positions.length; j += 2) {

                float x = positions[j];
                float y = positions[j + 1];

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(x))
                    break;

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(x) || !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(y))
                    continue;

                Entry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j / 2 + mXBounds.min);

                if (dataSet.isDrawValuesEnabled()) {
                    //drawValue(c, formatter.getPointLabel(entry), x, y - valOffset, dataSet.getValueTextColor(j / 2));
                    drawValue(c, formatter.getPointLabel(entry), x, y+textHeight*0.35f, dataSet.getValueTextColor(j / 2));
                }

                if (entry.getIcon() != null && dataSet.isDrawIconsEnabled()) {

                    Drawable icon = entry.getIcon();

                    Utils.drawImage(
                            c,
                            icon,
                            (int)(x + iconsOffset.x),
                            (int)(y + iconsOffset.y),
                            icon.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                            icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
                }
            }

            MPPointF.recycleInstance(iconsOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

}

3.Set your own LineChart renderer to your modified drawValues class

```
LineChart mChart = (LineChart) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.LineChart);

mChart.setRenderer(new CenteredTextLineChartRenderer(mChart,mChart.getAnimator(),mChart.getViewPortHandler()));
```

4. Run your code and manually adapt the 0.35f offset in your CenteredTextLineChartRenderer class

[Now your text is always vertically centered!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF2we.png)

IMPORTANT: With deleting the valOffset your label is not vertically centered as the text anchor is not in the center of your text label. So you have to insert a manual offset "textHeight*0.35f" (just try it out).